# Hide line of descriptive list

Tags: html

The following is my situation:

I have a page that is dynamically created with a descriptive list of texts with accompanying checkboxes.

I can check whether a checkbox is created through it having the attribute of "checked" when a page is loaded.
Such a checkbox is always situated in a < dd >-element with an accompanying < dt >-element.

Can i remove/hide this line of dd & dt without any other identifying aides like id's or classes by using JS or JQuery ?

See a code-example below for clarification of the piece of the list i wand to hide if checked="checked" for the input:

```
<dt>Some descriptive text</dt>
<dd>
    <input disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" name="somename" checked="checked">
</dd>
```

Comment: Please provide your code, it will be easier to understand and help

Comment: Welcome to SO: Please visit the [help] to se why your question is voted down and possibly closed as off-topic. HINT: Post effort and CODE

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone interested in the solution, this is how i solved it:

```
if(document.getElementById('thePage')){
    $("[checked=checked]").parent().prev().hide();
    $("[checked=checked]").hide();
}
```